# C++ Communication via COM Port

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

How can one communicate with a device via a COM port with C++? Is there a windows library which handles this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Im using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of sample code on the web if you Google. Here's one example: http://web.archive.org/web/20220426073821/http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf

Comment: When I follow the link, it says "The service is unavailable."  The latest version I found using the Wayback Machine is at http://web.archive.org/web/20220426073821/http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf.  Should the link be updated?

Comment: I think it's bad form to send a link to another site rather than post a code example or a link to another StackOverflow post. Thankfully Captain Oblivious posted an example very similar to the pdf you linked to.

Comment: Agreed. But that was 11 years ago. I don't think I exhibit such laziness often.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the general file I/O API calls such as `CreateFile()` and `ReadFile()` to accomplish this. Additional calls such as `GetCommState()` and `SetCommState()` can be used to change the various settings of the serial port once it has been opened.

```
HANDLE hSerial;
hSerial = CreateFile(
    "COM1",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0);
if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        //serial port does not exist. Inform user.
    }
    //some other error occurred. Inform user.
}


DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
dcbSerial.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
{
    //error getting state
}
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_19200;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;
if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
{
    //error setting serial port state
}
```