# How to write c++ dll function to get com port Reading

Tags: c++, function, dll

all i am new to c++ , and i tried to get COM port reading from function in c++
Below is the stating of code , can anyone help me to finish this ?
The function should Fetch the Values as commented, Please help me 
Thanking you

```
int ComPortReading( short, wchar_t * Data[], wchar_t **Output, SIZE_T *OutputSize )
{
int result = 1;
if( Data[0] )
{
    *OutputSize = 50;
    *Output = (wchar_t *) CoTaskMemAlloc(*OutputSize);

    if( *Output )
    {
        wchar_t *EndPtr;

        double v11 = wcstod(Data[0], &EndPtr);  // Port Name
        double v12 = wcstod(Data[1], &EndPtr);  // Baud Rate
        double v13 = wcstod(Data[2], &EndPtr);  // Data Bits
        double v14 = wcstod(Data[3], &EndPtr);  // Stop Bits
        double v15 = wcstod(Data[4], &EndPtr);  // Parity

 // Need to write code here to read COM port
       // Com port settings can be taken from the above v11 - v15 values

        swprintf(*Output, L"%.10lf", v11);
        result = 0;
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that actually reads bytes from a COM port, so really you are asking something about C++ strin processing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Communication via COM Port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035294/c-communication-via-com-port)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a library, which encapsulate the hard stuff. For example [this library on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C) or the implementation from [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/boost_asio).

Comment: Sir, can u complete the function please ?